The z-index always destroys my header how can I fix it?
I want to give my header a z-Index, but every time I put it on the header gets fully destroyed and idk how I can fix it.
Also my boxes are overlapping my navbar/header, can I fix it with the z-index?


body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  background: #DCdCdC
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 650;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 400px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.products .box-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.products .box-container .box {
  flex: 1 1 30rem;
  box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  border: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s;
  z-index: 0;
}

.products .box-container .box .image {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  z-index: 0;
}

.products .box-container .box .image .icons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.products .box-container .box .image .icons a {
  margin-left: 8rem;
  margin-bottom: -3rem;
  height: 4rem;
  line-height: 6rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  width: 50% background: black);
  color: #000;
}

.products .box-container .box .content {
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.products .box-container .box .content h3 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #000;
}

.products .box-container .box .content price {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
<div class="header">
  <a href="1-Seite.html" class=l ogo>fashion</a>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="1-Seite.html">Home</a>
    <a href="2-Seite.html">Shop</a>
    <a href="#">Über uns</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<section class="products" id="products">
  <h1 class="heading"> latest <span> products</span> </h1>
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="bb.hoodie.png" width="50%;" id="box" alt="">
        <div class="icons">
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
          <a href="#" class="cart-btn">add to cart</a>
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>MEDIUM FIT B HOODIE</h3>
        <div class="price"> 1.225€ <span></span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="bbjacke.png" width="50%;" id="box" alt="">
        <div class="icons">
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
          <a href="#" class="cart-btn">add to cart</a>
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>RACING JACKET</h3>
        <div class="price"> 3.100€ <span></span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="nfs.hose.png" width="50%;" alt="">
        <div class="icons">
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
          <a href="#" class="cart-btn">add to cart</a>
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>HEAVY WASHED BOMBER</h3>
        <div class="price">2.175€ <span></span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="nfs.bomber.png" width="50%;" alt="">
        <div class="icons">
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
          <a href="#" class="cart-btn">add to cart</a>
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>GREY INSIDE OUT BOMBER</h3>
        <div class="price"> 2.750€ <span></span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="ro.coat.png" width="50%;" alt="">
        <div class="icons">
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
          <a href="#" class="cart-btn">add to cart</a>
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>HOODED COAT GREY/BLACK </h3>
        <div class="price"> 4.250€ <span> </span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="ro.coat 2.png" width="50%;" alt="">
        <div class="icons">
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
          <a href="#" class="cart-btn">add to cart</a>
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>HOODED COAT BLACK</h3>
        <div class="price"> 4.250€ <span> </span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




What do you mean, your header gets destroyed with z-index? Seems to be fine when I tried it in a jsfiddle

just wanted to highlight you have a missing closing </section> .. but that's not the issue. Did you try to add z-index: 1; to the .header element?  you styled the header with position: fixed so The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.. Plus it will always stay on top of the viewport while scrolling the page...so it will look like the .box elements are "overlapping". But yet the header should cover the underlying document (try the zindex strategy)

@RahulMehta idk, as soon as I give my header a z-index all my different stuff in the header is moving to the left side and looses the color font etc.

@DiegoD thats what I tryed and what my question was. everytime i give my .head a zindex everything moves to the left and looses the color

to start off with, you have a few errors with your code on Line 88 to 90.
And though I can't fix your first problem, I can answer your question regarding z-index and your boxes overlapping your nav bar/header. If you want your "boxes" underlapping(the opposite of overlapping) the nav bar/header, then yes you can uze Z-index. If you want it below, then you must use breaks or other HTML components. You can also use CSS components that relate to position.(Please Note That Z-Index Isn't The Only Way To Make Something Underlap)

The only reason I can think of it not working for you is that you did not have a ; at the end of background property for the header


body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding:19px 20px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 10;
}

.logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding:20px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 650;
}

.navbar a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: 600; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    margin-left: 400px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.products {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.products .box-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1.5rem;
}

.products .box-container .box{
    flex:1 1 15rem;
    box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1.5rem rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    border: .1rem solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.products .box-container .box .image{
    position:relative;
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top: 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box:hover{
    transform:scale(1.05);
}

.products .box-container .box .image .icons {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left:0; right: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.products .box-container .box .image .icons a {
    margin-left: 8rem;
    margin-bottom: -3rem;
    height: 4rem;
    line-height:6rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    width: 50%
    background: black);
    color:#000;
}

.products .box-container .box .content {
    padding:2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.products .box-container .box .content h3 {
    font-size:2rem;
    color: #000;
}

.products .box-container .box .content price {
    font-size:1.5rem;
    color: black;
    font-weight:bolder;
    padding-top:1rem;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>fashion</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_2_Seite.css" media="all" />
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href= "1-Seite.html" class= logo>fashion</a>
            <nav class="navbar">
                <a href="1-Seite.html">Home</a>
                <a href="2-Seite.html">Shop</a>
                <a href="#">Über uns</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
    
    <section class="products" id="products">
        <h1 class="heading"> latest <span> products</span> </h1>
        <div class="box-container">
            
            <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="bb.hoodie.png" width="50%;" id="box" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>MEDIUM FIT B HOODIE</h3>
                    <div class="price"> 1.225€ <span></span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
            <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="bbjacke.png" width="50%;" id="box" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>RACING JACKET</h3>
                    <div class="price"> 3.100€ <span></span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
            <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="nfs.hose.png" width="50%;" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>HEAVY WASHED BOMBER</h3>
                    <div class="price">2.175€ <span></span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        
            <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="nfs.bomber.png" width="50%;" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>GREY INSIDE OUT BOMBER</h3>
                    <div class="price"> 2.750€ <span></span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
        <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="ro.coat.png" width="50%;" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>HOODED COAT GREY/BLACK </h3>
                    <div class="price"> 4.250€ <span> </span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
        <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="ro.coat 2.png" width="50%;" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>HOODED COAT BLACK</h3>
                    <div class="price"> 4.250€ <span> </span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
        
        
        
    </div>
                
                        
        

    </body>
</html>




You're welcome :) Would appreciate you upvoting the answer and marking it as accepted/solved.
